# absolutely convergent integral and an additional question on asymptotics

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, absolute-convergence

I want to show that the integral
$$\int_1^{\infty}e^{-a(x-\ln(x))}\frac{x}{e^{cx}(1+x^2)}dx$$ is absolutely convergent by the dominated convergence theorem.
So I figured that since
$$e^{-a(x-\ln(x))}\frac{x}{e^{cx}(1+x^2)} \leq e^{-2bx}x^{a}$$
where $b=\max\{a,c\}$ one gets
$$\int_1^{\infty}e^{-a(x-\ln(x))}\frac{x}{e^{cx}(1+x^2)}dx \leq \int_1^{\infty}e^{-2bx}x^{a}dx=2^{a-1}b^{-a-1} \Gamma(a+1,2b)<\infty$$
which completes the proof. Is that correct?
In addition I want to find coefficients $g_k$ so that
$$1-\frac{1}{t} \sim \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+2)g_k(t-1)^k, \qquad{t \rightarrow 1}$$
My solution is $g_0=0$ and $g_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{k+2}$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: By the geometric series, $$
1 - \frac{1}{t} = \frac{{t - 1}}{{1 + (t - 1)}} = (t - 1)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k (t - 1)^k }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{k + 1} (t - 1)^k } ,
$$ for $|t-1|<1$. Regarding the integral, you need some conditions on $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to mention that a,c>0. That must be sufficient at least to my understanding. correct?:)